# Unions and Intersects of Intervals

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

[image: Question]

I think part (a) was fine, I got (0,1/3) and (0, 1/7). 

I've never seen the notation used in (b) and (c), my guess is that (b) is asking for the union of all Bn where n is an element of A so I'd have thought it would be (0,1) if n was the natural numbers but since it's only a subset I'm not sure if we can be sure that 1 is an element of A which would change the union? 

For (c) I'm guessing that means the intersect of all Bn where n is a natural number, I'm unsure about this one too since the limit of 1/n as n approaches infinity will go to 0, would this leave [0] as the answer? 

Again I have never seen unions and intersects written this way so I'm just making assumptions. 

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

$\bigcup_{n \in A}B_n$ is the union of $B_n$ where $n$ comes from the set $A$.

$$\bigcup_{n \in A}B_n = \left\{x: \exists n \in A, x \in B_n \right\}$$

Similarly for the intersection notation.

$$\bigcap_{n \in A}B_n = \left\{x: \forall n \in A, x \in B_n \right\}$$

We have 
$$B_n \subset B_{n-1} \subset \ldots B_2 \subset B_1.$$

Check that:

$$\bigcup_{n \in A}B_n = B_{\min_{n \in A}n}=\left(0, \frac1{\min_{n \in A}n}\right)$$

For the last part, the answer can't be $\{0\}$ because $0$ is not in any of the set.

Check that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}B_n = \emptyset$. Try to see this by contradiction, suppose it is not empty and there is an element $x$, try to construct a $B_n$ such that it doesn't contain $x$.